# EF6 - not doing what I expected for .Any()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5

I am stumped by EF 6 .... I have a web application which behaves very badly in terms of performance. While analysing, I found one of the culprits being a method of mine that checks whether a collection is empty (or not) on an EF6 entity.

Basically, I have:

```
public partial class BaseEntity
{
    public int BaseEntityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // a few more properties, of no concern here....

    // a lazily loaded collection of subitems        
    public virtual ICollection<Subitem> Subitems { get; set; }
}

public partial class Subitem
{
    public int SubitemId { get; set; }
    public int BaseEntityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // a few more properties, of no concern here....
}
```

In my app, I need to check whether or not a given instance of `BaseEntity` is "empty" - which is defined as having no subitems. So I added this method `CheckIfEmpty` to a second partial class file:

```
public partial class BaseEntity
{
    public bool IsEmpty 
    {
        return !Subitems.Any();
    }
}
```

Now a single `BaseEntity` can have hundreds or thousands of subitems - so I wanted to use the most efficient way to check whether or not there were any subitems. My **assumption** was that calling `.Any()` on a collection that's not been loaded yet from the database would basically translate into a

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Subitems) ......
```

SQL call - or something along those lines - just checking to see if any items existed - or not. I specifically picked `.Any()` over `.Count > 0` because I know that checking for the count will need to enumerate the whole collection and thus is highly inefficient when I just want to know if (or not) any items exist.

I **don't need to know** how many exist, nor am I interested in their details - just a simple *YES* or *NO* to the `is empty?` question would suffice.

To my big astonishment (and bedazzlement), it turns out EF6 turns this simple `.Any()` call into a `SELECT` statement that loads the **whole collection!** - that's definitely **NOT** what I had bargained for......

So is there any easy way to simply check **if a not-yet-loaded collection** has any values - or not - **WITHOUT** loading the complete collection from the database??

Comment: Calling `Subitems` loads all items even before `.Any` is reached, this is how lazy loading is implemented. The first time you access `Subitems` it is loaded. I try never to use lazy loading, but it does complicate my code: I tend to close the context as soon as possible, and open another another one for the `db.Subitem.Any(si=>si. BaseEntityId == ...)`

Comment: `SubItems` is an `ICollection`. It might work as you expect if it was an `IQueryable` (I'm not sure though, and I don't know if lazy loading can work with `IQueryable`)

Comment: By using an Eager loading approach and querying the DbSet, you get what you want: 

context.Set<TEntity>().Any(); is translated into:

SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [TEntity] AS [m])
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END

Comment: The docs on msdn have some solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @alessalessio: thanks - never thought of "reversing" the checking this way - but you're 100% right - with this, EF behaves as I had expected and does a simply `IF EXISTS()` check and performs extremely well - thank you!

Comment: @JakubLortz: thanks for that link - great way to do it, too - and it performs really well, thank you!

Comment: @marc_s glad it helped. i ll add an answer then. tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using an Eager loading approach and querying the DbSet, you get what you want:

`context.Set<TEntity>().Any();`

is translated into:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM [TEntity] AS [m]) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

Comment: Thanks again - great answer. I've modified it slightly to use `context.Subitems.Any(si => si.BaseEntityId == 42);` and this also works very nicely. Great approach - thanks!